# can't install CherryPy with python3.3 under ubuntu12.04

Tags: cherrypy, python-3.3, setup.py

I tried to install CherryPy under Ubuntu 12.04.3 server with command:

```
sudo python3.3 setup.py install
```

It seems that everything was fine.

But when running test:

```
python3.3 -c "import cherrypy"
```

it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
from cherrypy import process
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from cherrypy.process import plugins, servers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/plugins.py", line 424, in <module>
class PerpetualTimer(threading._Timer):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Timer'
```

When doing the same with

```
python2.7 -c "import cherrypy"
```

it gives no output.

What could it be?

Best regards,
Leonid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded CherryPy 3.2.3 from python.org (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CherryPy/3.2.3) instead of 3.2.2 taken from cherrypy.org (http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.2.2/) used before and run installation process once more.

Now it works for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

"Timer class was renamed from _Timer to Timer in Python 3.3"

https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1163/attributeerror-in-cherrypyprocessplugins

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I work with Cherrypy and I install this with Mako always with Terminal writing:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion python-mako python-simplejson python-cherrypy3 graphviz
```

This I find inside the [site](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/xenwebmanager/wiki/GettingStarted), you can save this in bookmarks' s browser.

Installation simpler and faster